# Unmet requirements: gulp exists

Tags: teamcity, gulp

I am currently doing a TeamCity build using the Gulp Runner and using the System-wide gulp setting.

The agents I have fail to meet the requirement

Unmet requirements: gulp exists

Where is it looking for gulp?

I have tried npm install -g gulp and installed gulp globally but I am not having much luck.

How do I meet the build agents requirement for gulp?

Comment: TeamCity defines a lot of those settings through Agent Parameters.  If you click on Agents -> then click the link of the agent name to get the details -> then agent parameters tab.  View the System Properties, the Env Variables and Config Parameters to see if gulp is referenced anywhere in there.  If not, maybe add a path to the executable to the %PATH% env var in the very least and restart the agent. 

Sometimes restarting the agent and/or server fixes those issues as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try to add this line

```
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules/
```

to end of `buildAgent.properties`. This shows to teamcity agent that you have `gulp` and all needed `nodejs`'s modules

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and I have just solved it by changing the account that the build agent runs under. when you run the agent installer you get the option to use the system account or a user account. I had used the system account but I installed node, npm and gulp under my user account so the agent didn't have access to it.

so the quickest solution is to run the build agent installer again and at the end select a user account to run the service under

Comment: You don't have to change the user account for the build agent. If gulp is installed under the user account, only the PATH is set in the environment variables for that user. You have to change the system wide path, than the system account has access to gulp as well.

Comment: You have to add C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm or something simular to the path. This is where the gulp command lives.

Comment: And restart server to make sure the path is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding to the PATH the user npm path, for example, C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm and then restart build agent.

On this folder you can see gulp files like "gulp" and "gulp.cmd".